# Find method parameter type or parameter generic type

Tags: java, generics

I need to find if my current class has method with a parameter that either its type is Integer of its generic type is Integer.

I wrote the following in main:

```
public static main(String[] args){
   Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("Test");
   Class<?> lookingForClass = Integer.class;
   Method[] method = clazz.getMethods();
   for (int i = 0; i < method.length; i++) {
       Type[] types = method[i].getGenericParameterTypes();
       for (int j = 0; j < types.length; j++) {
           Type type = types[j];
           Class<?> result = type.getClass();
           if (type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
               ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) type;
               Type[] fieldArgTypes = pt.getActualTypeArguments();
               result = (Class<?>) fieldArgTypes[0];
           }
           if (result instanceof lookingForClass)
               System.out.println("found it");
           }
      }
}

public static void findTowInArray(List<Integer> A) {

}

public static void findTowInArray(Integer A) {

}

public static void findTowInArray(String A) {

}
```

However I get a compilation error on `if (result instanceof lookingForClass)`

```
Incompatible conditional operand types Class<capture#6-of ?> and lookingForClass
```

What is wrong?

Comment: You possibly meant: `if (result.isAssignableFrom(lookingForClass))`?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751550/java-instanceof-operator)

Comment: @assylias it works only for findTowInArray(List<Integer> A) and not for findTowInArray(Integer A) as type.getClass() in the second method returns class

Comment: @assylias I think the right way is `lookingForClass.isAssignableFrom(result)`

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup I tried to write if (result.isInstance(lookingForClass)) but it would work return true only if the parameter type is List<Integer>. Since if it's Integer, Class<?> result = type.getClass(); returns Class and not Integer. How can I get the Integer from type if it's not parameterized?

Comment: @AleksG it still doesn't work for me as it doesn't find findTowInArray(Integer A) which is also valid

Comment: `lookingForClass.isAssignableFrm(result)` will check if `result` is a subclass of `Integer`.  If you need specifically `Integer` and not any of its subclasses, you can then use `if(result.equals(lookingForClass))`

Comment: Thanks. I answered my question based on all of your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gathering all the comments above, the solution was to do:

```
if (lookingForClass.isAssignableFrom(result) || type.equals(lookingForClass))
    System.out.println("found it");
```

and not

```
if (result instanceof lookingForClass)
```

Answer (score 1):

If a Type is already a class don't call getClass() on it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException{
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("Test");
    Class<?> lookingForClass = Integer.class;
    Method[] methods = clazz.getMethods();
    for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
        Method method = methods[i];
        Type[] types = method.getGenericParameterTypes();
        for (int j = 0; j < types.length; j++) {
            Type type = types[j];
            Class<?> result = type instanceof Class<?> ? (Class<?>)type : type.getClass();
            if (type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
                ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) type;
                Type[] fieldArgTypes = pt.getActualTypeArguments();
                result = (Class<?>) fieldArgTypes[0];
            }
            if (result.equals(lookingForClass))
                System.out.println("found " + method);
            }
       }
 }
```

And I would prefer loops like

```
for (final Method method : methods) {
    ...
}
```

if you don't need the index.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using below code, you have to compare type and Integer.class

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("Test");
        Class<Integer> lookingForClass = Integer.class;
        Method[] method = clazz.getMethods();
        for (int i = 0; i < method.length; i++)
        {
            Type[] types = method[i].getParameterTypes();

            for (int j = 0; j < types.length; j++)
            {
                Type type = types[j];
                Class<?> result = type.getClass();
                if (type instanceof ParameterizedType)
                {
                    ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) type;
                    Type[] fieldArgTypes = pt.getActualTypeArguments();
                    result = (Class<?>) fieldArgTypes[0];
                }
                if (type ==  lookingForClass)
                    System.out.println("found it");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I should get found it twice, but get it only once. It doesn't work

Comment: `type == lookingForClass` will not work, as you are comparing memory addresses.

Comment: Generally yes, but in this case not right, see: [Java equals for a Class. Is == same as .equals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322469/java-equals-for-a-class-is-same-as-equals)

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the type because of [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Java compiler will "Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or Object if the type parameters are unbounded".
For example:

```
public class Test<T> {
    public void setT(T t) {}
}
```

compiles to

```
public class Test {
    public void setT(Object t) {}
}
```

So it is not possible to get the type information at runtime.
See also related question:
[Get the generic type of an extending generic class in the constructor of the superclass in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801808/get-the-generic-type-of-an-extending-generic-class-in-the-constructor-of-the-sup)